# How can I change my username? I want to change it from user and numbers

Tags: support, user-profiles, username

Currently my username (display name) is the word "user", followed by a series of numbers. How can I change it to the name of my choosing?

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to change your account information, including the *Display Name*, [here](https://superuser.com/users/edit/233049). You reach this page by clicking on your own user name at the top of the page, then *edit*.

Comment: If you click your username from here you will also need to click `main user` before the `edit` option pops up.